# Failed to start MongoDB with deployed

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I will run deployed [look here what dpd is](http://deployd.com) on my server (Ubuntu 14.04).
I have installed every needed dependency.

When I try to run `dpd` I get the error `starting deployd v0.7.0... Failed to start MongoDB`.

So I tried `DEBUG=* dpd -d` and I get this

```
starting deployd v0.7.0...
mongod starting mongod +0ms
mongod <Buffer 32 30 31 34 2d 30 38 2d 30 35 54 31 31 3a 34 35 3a 32 30 2e 38 36 39 2b 30 32 30 30 20 5b 69 6e 69 74 61 6e 64 6c 69 73 74 65 6e 5d 20 4d 6f 6e 67 6f 44 ...> +28ms
mongod <Buffer 32 30 31 34 2d 30 38 2d 30 35 54 31 31 3a 34 35 3a 32 30 2e 38 37 31 2b 30 32 30 30 20 5b 69 6e 69 74 61 6e 64 6c 69 73 74 65 6e 5d 20 64 62 20 76 65 72 ...> +2ms
mongod <Buffer 32 30 31 34 2d 30 38 2d 30 35 54 31 31 3a 34 35 3a 32 30 2e 38 37 31 2b 30 32 30 30 20 5b 69 6e 69 74 61 6e 64 6c 69 73 74 65 6e 5d 20 67 69 74 20 76 65 ...> +0ms
mongod <Buffer 32 30 31 34 2d 30 38 2d 30 35 54 31 31 3a 34 35 3a 32 30 2e 38 39 30 2b 30 32 30 30 20 5b 69 6e 69 74 61 6e 64 6c 69 73 74 65 6e 5d 20 65 78 63 65 70 74 ...> +19ms
mongod <Buffer 32 30 31 34 2d 30 38 2d 30 35 54 31 31 3a 34 35 3a 32 30 2e 38 39 30 2b 30 32 30 30 20 5b 69 6e 69 74 61 6e 64 6c 69 73 74 65 6e 5d 20 64 62 65 78 69 74 ...> +1ms
mongod exit code 100 +2ms
Failed to start MongoDB
mongod error: 1 +1ms
mongod killing mongod +0ms
```

mongodb is running on my server correctly, because I can call `mongo` in Terminal and I get this

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3
connecting to: test
>
```

Comment: most likely deployd cannot start another mongod on the same port with the same lock file as such it quits

Comment: so have I understand it right? I have to stop mongod with 'sudo service mongod stop' and than call dpd in deployed project directory?

Comment: Yeah exactly, since dpd seems like it wants to take control of stopping/starting the service

Comment: so I have sudo service mongod status >>> mongod stop/waiting. Then I'm calling sudo dpd and I get this 
starting deployd v0.7.0...
Failed to start MongoDB  :/ :(

Comment: Same issue here. Any other ideas?

Comment: I have also checked that mongoDB (mongod) is in my PATH Variable. :/

Comment: have the same issue, starting dpd as super user 'sudo dpd' makes it run...

Comment: I confirm that running dpd with sudo works! However, this is quite boring (despite it's better than not running :-). Maybe does anyone figured out a definitive workaround for running dpd normally (as a regular user, for instance) on OSX? BTW, thanks and congrats to @IljaSucharev. This is the only solution I've found (and actually worked) after two days of googlings...

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem when using my deployd-app in a vagrant shared folder over NFS (network file system). MongoDB doesn't like to operate over NFS.

> Performance problems arise when both the data files and the journal
>   files are hosted on NFS. You may experience better performance if you
>   place the journal on local or iscsi volumes. If you must use NFS, add
>   the following NFS options to your /etc/fstab file: bg, nolock, and
>   noatime.
>   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/#remote-filesystems

Alternative: Try to run your app in a non-shared folder